# Extrair coluna de arquivo csv e converter o tipo de dado

Tags: python, funções, csv, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer uma função para extrair os dados de um arquivo .csv em uma lista, e preciso usar os condicionais if/elif/else para fazer a conversão do tipo de dado (de str para int). Só que não estou conseguindo fazer essa conversão, e continua me retornando a lista em str apenas.

A função:

```
def extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo: str, indice_coluna: int, tipo_dado: str):
  coluna = []
  with open (file = nome_arquivo, mode ='r', encoding = 'utf8' ) as arquivo:
    linha = arquivo.readline()
    linha = arquivo.readline()
    
    while linha:
      linha_separada = linha.split(sep = ',')
      if tipo_dado=='str':
        coluna.append(linha_separada[indice_coluna])   
      elif tipo_dado=='int':
        coluna.append(linha_separada[indice_coluna])
               
      else:
        print("erro")

      linha = arquivo.readline()

  return coluna
```

O teste dela com o retorno dando errado:

```
# extrair a coluna pessoas
pessoas = extrai_coluna_csv(nome_arquivo='./carros.csv', indice_coluna=4, tipo_dado='int')
print(pessoas) # deve retornar [2, 2, 2, ...]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver esse problema? Obrigada!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que você não está convertando o dado do tipo string para int. Pelo que eu entendi, caso você passe o valor de tipo_dado como "int", você deve converter os números de string para int antes de adicioná-los na array "colunas".

```py
elif tipo_dado=='int':
        coluna.append(int(linha_separada[indice_coluna]))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada! Estava quebrando a cabeça há dias e tentando de diferentes formas e nunca conseguia converter kkkk. Mais fácil do que eu imaginava, obrigada mesmo!

Comment: @Carolina Por nada! Se possível marque a resposta como aceita pra indicar que o problema foi solucionado.